Operation on all columns of a type in modern Polars
I have a piece of code that works in Polars 0.20.19, but I don't know how to make it work in Polars 1.10.
The working code (in Polars 0.20.19) is very similar to the following:
def format_all_string_fields_polars() -> pl.Expr:
  return (
      pl.when(
          (pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip().str.lengths() == 0) | # ERROR ON THIS LINE
          (pl.col(pl.Utf8) == "NULL")
      )
      .then(None)
      .otherwise(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip())
      .keep_name()
  )

df.with_columns(format_all_string_fields_polars())

I have converted the pl.Utf8 dtype to pl.String, but it keeps giving me the same error:

AttributeError: 'ExprStringNameSpace' object has no attribute 'strip'

The function is supposed to perform the When-Then operation on all string fields of the dataframe, in-place, but return all columns in the dataframe (including the non-string columns as well).
How do I convert this function to a working piece of code in Polars 1.10?


pl.Utf8 was renamed to pl.String
.str.strip() was renamed to .str.strip_chars()
.str.lengths() was split into .str.len_chars() and .str.len_bytes()
.keep_name() was renamed to .name.keep()

def format_all_string_fields_polars() -> pl.Expr:
  return (
      pl.when(
          (pl.col(pl.String).str.strip_chars().str.len_chars() == 0) | 
          (pl.col(pl.String) == "NULL")
      )
      .then(None)
      .otherwise(pl.col(pl.String).str.strip_chars())
      .name.keep()
  )


@ViníciusQueiroz There is also the Polars discord where you're allowed to act human.

jqurious already shared the correct "translation" of your code snippet to Polars 1.10.0.
Alternatively, the snippet can be simplified as follows.
def format_all_string_fields_polars() -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col(pl.String).str.strip_chars().replace({"": None, "NULL": None})

